# Tool to retrieve coordinates from SVG file

Tags: software-recommendations, svg

I have an .SVG file of a map with known extreme North/South/East/West coordinates of the area, and I'm required to retrieve coordinates of certain points on it.

What free/freeware software tools, capable of running on Windows 10 x64 (LTSB) I could use for that purpose?

Comment: Please add your OS and what you are wiling to pay.

Answer (score 1):

It's not clear exactly what you want to do here.
If you want to do it visually - clicking on points and reading their coordinates - then [Inkscape](http://inkscape.org) will almost certainly do the job.

If you want to automate things, then you *might* be able to use some sort of GIS solution, but you might be best to write something yourself. SVG files consist of text (I think probably XML-based?), so shouldn't be too hard to parse. There might even be existing libraries for the purpose for R or similar.

Comment: +1 for inkscape. Resize your map so the internal coordinates in Inkscape match the coordinates on the map, and then just manually pick the points. Could be a better way to do it though using GIS tools.

Answer (score 0):

You'll probably need to digitize the map. QGis is highly likely to help, and it's free! 
https://www.qgistutorials.com/en/docs/digitizing_basics.html